# No regions in regionmanager using Microsoft Dependency Injection in prism application (7.2)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.1, prism-7

**I am using Prism v7.2.0.1422 for a WPF app with .net Core 3.1.
I am using the Microsoft Dependency Injection for DI.**

I don't want use Unity container.
regionAdapterMappings is empty.
View discovery and view injection don't work.
what do I need to be able to register regions in regionManager ?

**MyPrismApplication.cs**

```
        public abstract class MyPrismApplication : PrismApplicationBase
        {            
            protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
            {
                return PrismContainerExtension.Current;
            }

            protected override void RegisterRequiredTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
            {
                base.RegisterRequiredTypes(containerRegistry);
    
                containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IRegionNavigationContentLoader, RegionNavigationContentLoader>();
                containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IServiceLocator, MicrosoftServiceLocatorAdapter>();
            }
    
            protected override void ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings(RegionAdapterMappings regionAdapterMappings)
            {
                base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings(regionAdapterMappings);
    
                //Fix bug when RegionAdapterMappings are not registered into dependency container
                PrismContainerExtension.Current.RegisterInstance(regionAdapterMappings);
            }             
            
        }
```

the boolean requiresRebuild destroy all instances inside the container.

> Prism v7.2.0.1422.
> .net Core 3.1
> Prism.Container.Extensions v7.2.0.54.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that is currently supported out of the box. If you look back at the Prism 7.2 source code for either [DryIoc](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/v7.2.0.1422/Source/Wpf/Prism.DryIoc.Wpf) or [Unity](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/v7.2.0.1422/Source/Wpf/Prism.Unity.Wpf), you'll see that there is some additional container work which cannot be abstracted out in the PrismContainerExtensions. Specifically you'll need to create ServiceLocatorAdapter.

This requirement goes away for Prism 8, however I have not had the time to update the Prism Container Extensions for Prism 8 and won't until after the next Prism 8 preview. In the mean time I suggest opening an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Container.Extensions/issues/new) to track WPF support for the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection container.

Comment: thanks, but i have already implemented ServiceLocatorImplBase.